# iPhone call forwarding

Tags: iphone, phone-call, forwarding

Is there any API to manage incoming call forwarding settings in iOS? Public (for AppStore) or private?
For instance, I have an array of caller/phone number pairs and if caller is from this array, I redirect his call to the corresponding number.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that there is no API for it in the official API.

On jail-broken phones there maybe some possibility, but I'm not in to jailbreak development.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up call forwarding (and many other phone features) from a phone keypad by dialing what are known as "GSM codes". I've never really thought about it, but I see no reason an app couldn't tell the phone app to dial such things with a standard "tel:" URL.

According to [this url](http://www.cutemachine.com/iphone-productivity-quick-tip/how-to-divert-calls-on-the-iphone-with-gsm-codes/), the code you're after is `**21*a phone number#`.

Go try dialing that via a url command, and let us know what you find out!

This is much lower resolution than you ask about in your question, of course. This will divert ALL calls to the given number. But maybe it can be used as a foundation for something.